# how to send a large base64 image to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js

im using this function to convert html div to pdf, but i want to store it on the server so i can then attach it to an email and send it using nodmailer, now my problem is that i dont know how to store it on the server,

frontEnd is `js`
backEnd is `nodejs`

all kind of help is appreciated so much

FRONT END `JS`

```
    html2canvas($(".html-content")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
   }
        
        $.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url: "/receive",
           data: imgData,
        })
    
    });
```

BACKEND `nodejs`

```
const express = require("express");
const router = require("express").Router();
router.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
router.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000}));


router.post('/receive', (req, res) => {
    
    console.log("my req body: ", req.body)
})
```

CONSOLE LOG

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
    at read (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
    at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:116:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:119:7)
```

> EDIT 1

setting a  `contentType: "image/jpeg"`, on ajax, gets rid of payload too large error, but nothing is displayed on  the back end,

```
console.log("reqbody: " +  req.body)
```

output

```
reqbody: [object Object]
```

Comment: What you're doing seems legit except that it's larger than the 50mb limit you self imposed.  How big is it? And is raising the limit an option?    Also [canvas.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) might be a better format.

Comment: it cant possibly be larger than 50 mb thats whats driving me crazy, the size of the pdf when downloaded is less than 1 mb.  im trying to figure out  how to send the DOM itself to the server then generate the image there, i also wanna figure out whether the max size actually  is set to 50 mb or not i dont know  how to check what the size limit is

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the way you are doing it (generating a pdf on the client and then sending it to the server to mail)

according to https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3082

you can put your pdf in a variable like this `pdf.output()`

but then you should not put it in the query - put it in the payload

something like

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: pdf.output(),
  // dataType: dataType // don't know if you need this too so it doesn't think it's json
});
```

and then to receive it on the server.  It won't be in the query string anymore; I think you can use express's "body parser middleware" to get the playload.

---

However, are you sure that you want to generate the pdf on the client and send it back to the server?  A user could intercept the ajax request and send a different PDF... which might not be an issue for some applications, but could be bad for others.

For most things I think it would be better to generate the pdf on the server and then send it to the browser to show (using an ajax request that sends the pdf the opposite way from what you have) and mail it at the same time.

Comment: first of all thank you so much for the ideas,  i tried your solution, it says on the web browser console this error:  413 (Payload Too Large).
at the moment i really just want it to work,  the pdf is just a payment receipt, thats attached to an email. whether i generate the pdf in the front end or back end its all the same, i just want it to work :( been at it all day,

Comment: and on the backend side console it says PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Comment: i uploaded my topic thats what i currently have, its past midnight im gonna go to sleep, i hope u take a look

Answer (score 0):

You encoded the canvas as a jpeg using `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);`, but I would suggest encoding using `canvas.toBlob` and setting an actual `contentType` of `image/jpeg` in the ajax call (instead of using the [default](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`) and then receive the [raw](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.raw) body using `express.raw({ type: '*/*', limit: '50mb'})`  (or you can set a more restrictive type to just `image/jpeg` or `image/*` or whatever is most appropriate for your application.)

In the client:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "/receive",
  data: imgData,
  contentType: "image/jpeg"
})
```

And in your server:

```
app.use(express.raw({ type: '*/*', limit: '50mb' }));
```

The incoming payload will be in `req.body` as a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Comment: hello thank you for replying, i set an actual contentType,  like you mentioned and that got rid of the payload exceeded error message, but printing this on the  backend console gives me this 

console.log("req-body: " + req.body)
 output :  req-body: [object Object]
i was happy for a moment, but now i think it got rid of the payload too large problem cuz it no longer sends any payload, i havent tried using  canvas.toblob yet though